# Selenium response code 500 on VM on local machine working

Tags: java, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

Hello I have Maven Selenium Cucumber project on my local machine everything is working. Im trying to launch it on Virtual machine via jenkins. after build starts i have this error on every test:
Versions:

```
ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.16 (7e1ff058633f5b79b1cd7479aca585ba385519d8-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#182})
Google Chrome 114.0.5735.198
```

```
Given Chrome browser is initalized                                                     # stepDefinitions.login.chrome_browser_is_initalized()
      org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
Host info: host: 'pdbnhpsron043', ip: '10.102.8.74'
Build info: version: '4.9.0', revision: 'd7057100a6'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.0-76-generic', java.version: '17.0.7'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*, --disable-dev-shm-usage, --no-sandbox, --ignore-certificate-errors, --remote-debugging-port=9222], extensions: []}}]}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:73)
    at stepDefinitions.MySharedClass.startBrowser(MySharedClass.java:32)
    at stepDefinitions.login.<init>(login.java:20)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
    at io.cucumber.picocontainer.PicoFactory.getInstance(PicoFactory.java:54)
    at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
    at io.cucumber.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:29)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreStepDefinition.execute(CoreStepDefinition.java:66)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:63)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:84)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:56)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:51)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:84)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:75)
    at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.lambda$run$0(PickleRunners.java:151)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$5(CucumberExecutionContext.java:137)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:137)
    at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:148)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:144)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:137)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:196)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runFeatures$6(CucumberExecutionContext.java:148)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.execute(CucumberExecutionContext.java:163)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runFeatures(CucumberExecutionContext.java:146)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber$StartAndFinishTestRun.evaluate(Cucumber.java:226)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:240)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495)

  And I go to url mtf-ref.telekom.de within Telekom network                              # stepDefinitions.login.i_go_to_url_mtf_ref_telekom_de_within_telekom_network()
  When I press button Anmeldung mit Passwort                                             # stepDefinitions.login.i_press_button_anmeldung_mit_passwort()
  And I enter "robo_sb_v_sp" in field Benutzername and "abcABC123!!!" in field Password. # stepDefinitions.login.i_enter_in_field_benutzername_and_in_field_password(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
  Then I press button Anmelden                                                           # stepDefinitions.login.i_press_button_anmelden()
  And Im logged in succesfully                                                           # stepDefinitions.login.im_logged_in_succesfully()
      java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot.getScreenshotAs(org.openqa.selenium.OutputType)" because "ts" is null
    at stepDefinitions.MySharedClass.closeBrowser(MySharedClass.java:45)
```

I updated to latest versions and i was thinking it will help. Watch ton of videos about trouble shooting nothing helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the following arguments incase they aren't mandatory:

- *`--remote-allow-origins=*`*
- *`--disable-dev-shm-usage`*
- *`--no-sandbox`*
- *`--ignore-certificate-errors`*

and retest. You should be good to go.

Comment: With your help it works now . Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

The selenium version you are using is `v4.9.0`. And the compatible browser for this version of selenium is as below:

[image]

Your browser is `v114`, see the supported version below:

[image]

Reference: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/CHANGELOG

**SOLUTION:** You need to switch to latest Selenium `v4.10.0`

Comment: Unfortumatelly it is not the case i tried it before. It is also not working. Maybe some security restriction on firewall?

Comment: Doesn't matters if there isn't a exact CDP match, _org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch_